# Set + operation with infinitely many inverses

Tags: group-theory

For my group theory homework I have to construct a set with an operation that has an identity in which every element is invertible and has infinitely many inverses (except for the identity). The only hint I have is that the operation will be quite artificial, so not some kind of combination of ordinary additions and multiplications of numbers. I then have to check that the operation fails associativity. Been working on it for a while now, but not really getting anywhere. I was hoping someone could provide me with another hint to get the thought process starting.

Comment: How about making every non-identity an inverse of every non-identity?